# Update to android studio to android-studio-2022.3.1.19 version problem

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

My android studio version is Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2,
and I tried to update to 2022.3.1.19.
I can open the new version,but when I open the old project.
That make some trouble... Is anybody know how to fix this problem?

[something build error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4gwH.png)

I try to "Invalidate Caches" and then "Sync project gradle" ,
but after sync the poroject and build > "A build operation project failed"

Comment: Please do not post error messages as screenshot. Just copy the full error text and paste it as text into your question.